# Affine transformations for twisting and pinching

Tags: image-processing

In image processing we can use affine transformations for translation, rotation, shear and scaling of pixels. But what kind of transformations are used for twisting and pinching of image pixels? Or what is mathematical definition for this kinds of transforms?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by twisting and pinching?  I want to make sure I understand.

Comment: One way of getting twisting and pinching is by transformations that are rotations or scaling of each pixel with respect to a center, but such that the angle of rotation and the scaling ratio depend on the distance of the pixel to such center. How that dependence is carried out is up to you. These aren't affine transformations, though, unless the dependence on the distance from the center is constant. The affine transformations are only compositions of the ones that you listed in the first sentence.

Comment: @plop Thank you! And I guess we could control the angle of rotation or scaling relationship on the distance by defining a custom falloff curve?

Comment: @D.W. I meant something like pinching and twirling distortion effects in Photoshop.

Comment: @LennyWhite Yes, for example, [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/image-twist-and-swirl-algorithm/2/) then are using `newAngle = originalAngle + 1/(factor*radius+(4.0f/C_PI))`, where `radius` is the distance from the center. So, the closer to the center the more they turn for this choice.

Comment: @plop Thanks! You said if the dependence on the distance from center is constant the transformation would be affine. Did you mean if the angle of rotation or scaling changes linearly with distance? If so I wonder how matrices for this type of transformations look like.

Comment: @LennyWhite When I said constant I meant constant, not linearly. In a rotation, the angle that a pixel rotates around the center of rotation is the same independently of the pixel. Well, except for the center itself, which doesn't have any angle. Similarly for a scaling (a homothety) the scaling ratio is independent of the pixel.

Comment: @plop Oh I see thanks for the help!